# I can't receive magnet-link metadata via libtorrent-python, without specifying udp-protocol of tracker

Tags: python, libtorrent

I'm using libtorrent in Python, but it doesn't recognize magnet link, which looks like magnet:?... with only sha1 hash, it needs to get &dn parameter to parse specific torrent-tracker.
By the way, qBitTorrent, which does use the same libtorrent lib can recognize only magnet link.

Comment: If you could post code to show what you've tried, it would help!

Answer (score 0):

If the magnet link doesn't have any trackers in it, then the client needs to have the DHT active and get peers that way instead.